# Can we manipulate state value of tree object by useState?

Tags: reactjs, tree, treeview, use-state, react-functional-component

If I have a **tree object** like this, is there any way to manipulate (pushing children/updating text) the particular children's value using **useState**? I'm creating a mind-map software, where I want to detect the user click event and grab the parentId to show the children below the parent.

```
const nestedData = {
    name: 'A',
    id: 0,
    parentId: null,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'b',
            id: 1,
            parentId: 0,
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'c',
            id: 2,
            parentId: 0,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'd',
                    id: 3,
                    parentId: 2,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'e',
                            id: 4,
                            parentId: 3,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'e',
                            id: 4,
                            parentId: 3,
                            children: [
                                {
                                    name: 'e',
                                    id: 5,
                                    parentId: 4,
                                    children: []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
}
const [data, setData] = useState(nestedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update a complex state object using the useState() hook.

For your case you can try like below code

```
const handleClick = () => {
    // First we clone the state
    let clonedData = {...data};
    // we manipulate it
    clonedData.name = "AZ";
    // or add new children
    clonedData.children[1].children.push(
               {
                 id: 100,
                 name: "ZZ",
                 parentId: 0,
                 children: []
               }
     );
    // or update existing child's content
    clonedData.children[1].children[0].children[1].children[0].name = "ZZZZ";
    // Then just update the state
    setData(clonedData);
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Well, thanks for commenting. But it doesn't look like dynamic. setState() can be done by this, however the problem I'm facing is detecting the exact parent. Like you wrote this, "clonedData.children[1].children[0].children[1].children[0].name". but we don't know how many children out there. It's length could be 2, 3, or 100 .

Comment: I did it like this, 

function addNewElement(element) {
        let clonedData = {...data}
        element.children.push({
            name : 'Newest Element'
        })
        console.log(element)
        setData(clonedData)
    }

But it only works for only parent object(I didn't try on the newest element cz it doesn't have an ID or parent ID). But after those set if I click on addNewElement(), it says setData() is not a function. setData has came through the props

Comment: What I gave you is just an idea. You have to implement the logic for detecting the exact parent. :). If setData comes through the props then you must call props.setData(clonedData);